# Chrome Download Progress Bar

Tags: google-chrome, download

When I download file or anything from the website, the download progress bar

will show automatically !

The normal display is : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN7E6.png)

However, my download progress bar is a little weird...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbF9G.jpg)

There is no file name, and progress...

just a picture of the file !

How can I fix it !!!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does it still respond to clicks the same way that a regular download bar would, or is it just completely dead space? Are you using a custom Chrome theme or the standard one?

Comment: Looks like a theme problem.